# Need to add rewrite rule that adds in additional information about the post to url

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

A have a post type for `venues` which have the attributes `title`, `state`, and `suburb`. Currently using the default WordPress permalinks I get the following format:

`mysite.com/venue/{title}`

However, I would like to have the full url be:

`mysite.com/venue/{state}/{suburb}/{title}`

This information is something that can be retrieved from the database, with permalinks off the url format for this would be:

`mysite.com/?venue=title`

I believe it's also possible to pull it by ID some how...

My question is, how do I create a rewrite rule that pulls this information based on `post_id` or `title` to create a url of this format?

Is it even possible?

Comment: How is state and suburb saved in the database: as metadata?  taxonomy?

Comment: @MannyFleurmond As fields using the plugin <a href="http://advancedcustomfields.com">ACF</a>. They can easily be stored as post metadata if that would solve this issue? I'm not sure how to do taxonomies but I could look into that and implement that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I took so long to write this up.  Hope it's still useful.

This is based off of a tutorial found [here](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2) and some general playing around.

```
<?php

//This function sets up the permastructure
add_action('init', 'setup_permastruct', 40);

function setup_permastruct() {
    //Setup query vars
    add_rewrite_tag('%state%','([^/]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%suburb%','([^/]+)');  
    
    //Permastruct for custom post type
    add_permastruct('venue', 'venue/%state%/%suburb%/%postname%', false);   
}

//This one fills in the blanks of your permastructure so that when WP makes a link for a venue, it creates it with all the right info
add_filter('post_type_link', 'create_permalink', 10, 4);

function create_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename, $sample) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $rewritecode = array(
        '%year%',
        '%monthnum%',
        '%day%',
        '%hour%',
        '%minute%',
        '%second%',
        $leavename? '' : '%postname%',
        '%post_id%',
        '%category%',
        '%author%',
        $leavename? '' : '%pagename%',
        '%state%',
        '%suburb%'
    );
    if ( '' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')) ) {
        $unixtime = strtotime($post->post_date);
 
        $category = '';
        if ( strpos($permalink, '%category%') !== false ) {
            $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
            if ( $cats ) {
                usort($cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID'); // order by ID
                $category = $cats[0]->slug;
                if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent )
                    $category = get_category_parents($parent, false, '/', true) . $category;
            }
            // show default category in permalinks, without
            // having to assign it explicitly
            if ( empty($category) ) {
                $default_category = get_category( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
                $category = is_wp_error( $default_category ) ? '' : $default_category->slug;
            }
        }
 
        $author = '';
        if ( strpos($permalink, '%author%') !== false ) {
            $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $author = $authordata->user_nicename;
        }
 
        $date = explode(" ",date('Y m d H i s', $unixtime));
        
        //Your custom data
        $state = get_post_meta($post_id, 'state_meta', true);
        $suburb = get_post_meta($post_id, 'suburb_meta', true);;
        
        //Enter permalink manipulations here            
        $rewritereplace = array(
            $date[0],
            $date[1],
            $date[2],
            $date[3],
            $date[4],
            $date[5],
            $post->post_name,
            $post->ID,
            $category,
            $author,
            $post->post_name,
            $state,
            $suburb
            //Add custom tag replacements here
        );
        $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
    }
    return $permalink;      
}
```

Key thing to notice is in the second function where I have the comment for your custom data.  Replace the second argument of the `get_post_meta` function calls with the names of your respective custom meta data.  After you insert the code, go to wp-admin>Settings>Permalinks and click save to refresh your rewrites and voila.

Let me know if you need clarifying on anything.

Comment: Won't this only affect the permalinks shown in WP Admin though? I can't get my actual URLs to show anything othe than 404 errors. Is there anywhere we can talk, over email?